# error: pcap library not found

Tags: linux, ubuntu-18.04

i tried to install reaver in my ubuntu 18.04 but i got that message

`checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for pcap_open_live in -lpcap... no
error: pcap library not found!`

but i already installed libpcap0.8 and libpcap0.8-dev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`configure` typically creates a log file which contains the exact error which was thrown by `gcc`. You'll have to investigate what the error was.

You can also open the `configure` script to see what exactly went wrong. The script will contain a test program which uses `pcap` and a command line used to compile it. You can copy the test program from there and try to compile manually using the same command line.

A likely cause of such errors is a missing or misconfigured `pkg-config`

Comment: it's works, the thing is that i missed to install 'libsqlite3-dev' library

Comment: and also sqlite3 library

Answer (score 1):

install libpcap-devel is necessary